# NodeJS Sequelize throwing error when trying to define model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am having trouble setting up `Sequelize` in my node application due to an error being thrown.

The error is as follows:

```
this.importCache[importPath] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I believe this has is being thrown at the `define` line within the model `globals.js` `const Communication = db.define('communication', {`

I tried to use `new` in front of the `db.define`, but then it complains and says that `db.define` is not a constructor.

Any ideas where I went wrong on this?

---

`server.js`

```
require("dotenv").config()
require("./models")

const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler"),
    producer = require("./producer"),
    express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    port = process.env.PORT || 5000,
    utilities = require("./utilities"),
    db = require("./config/db")

// Express Config
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Receive our incoming payload
app.post(
    "/payload",
    asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
        let result = await producer.sendToProducer(req.body)
        res.json(result);
    })
)

// Begin Listening
db.sync({}).then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        utilities.logError(`Server Listening...`)
    })
})
```

`./config/db.js`

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
```

`./models/index.js`

```
const db = require('../config/db');

const models = {
    Global: db.import('./global'),
};

Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
    if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
        models[modelName].associate(models);
    }
});

module.exports = models;
```

`./models/global.js`

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/db');

const Communication = db.define('communication', {

    message_uuid: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        unique: true,
    },
    firstname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    lastname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    age: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    department: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    campus: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    state: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },

});

module.exports = Communication;
```

Comment: What does this resolve to? `process.env.DATABASE_URL`

Answer (score 0):

Is your path incorrect for the const db in the global.js model? You're pathing to '../config/db' but the file is '../config/db.js'.

My understanding of how node works is that your path is leading to '../config/db/index.js'.